# Google tasks api java for sample desktop application

Tags: google-api-java-client, google-tasks-api

I want to create a Java desktop application to control Google tasks

but in Google tasks Api i found only samples for Android

Does that mean i can  only create tasks Api for android ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at all! Client libraries for the Tasks API, just like all Google APIs, is available on a number of different platforms. In addition, you can always make the REST calls yourself on any unsupported platform.

[This is where](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Tasks_API) you can download jars for any Java client application.  You'll find what you need in order to write an Android application, App Engine application, or a generic Java application all bundled inside.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/) is all the documentaion on the Tasks API. Pretty much any questions you have about the API in general should be answered there, as well as a "Getting Started" walkthrough and other helpful guides.

[Finally, here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/downloads) is a list of all client library platforms that Google generates for the Tasks API.

Comment: @elmetni Happy to help. Please feel free to [mark my answer as "accepted"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it answered your question. And if not, feel free to ask more.

Comment: done ..thank you again ... i was wondering if you know soemthing about 2-legged oauth authentication for google tasks api or Google calendar api ? i need a code source that s working with google client library 1.15 

so maybe you have an idea about that ?

Comment: @elmetni Certainly! There are a number of samples [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse?repo=samples) that include a working 2LO OAuth flow for basic, android, or App Engine. There's a calendar sample for each. The [Calendar Cmdline Sample](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-cmdline-sample/instructions.html) is an easy read through. It's currently for version 1.16.0-rc but you can always change the branch using the first link.